# Scope Chain in Titanium

Tags: javascript, scope, titanium, chain

I'm whondering how to access a specific method in a widget, which I've created.

```
var foo = {

    init : function() {
        $.bar.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    },

    handleClick : function(e) {
        console.log(this); // TiUIButton { widgetId="Ti.UI.Button:0" ...
        // I want to call baz() here....How to do that?
    },

    baz: function() {

    }
};

foo.init()
```

Greetings from germany and thanks for your help,

--marc

Comment: Just do: `foo.baz();`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

```
var foo = {

    init : function() {
        $.bar.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
    },

    handleClick : function(e) {
        console.log(this); // TiUIButton { widgetId="Ti.UI.Button:0" ...
        // I want to call baz() here....How to do that?
        // Like this
        foo.baz();
    },

    baz: function() {

    }
};

foo.init()
```